# php: не могу отловить ошибку во вложенном вызове функций

Tags: php, функции, циклы

Приветствую

Помогите отловить ошибку в коде. Никак не могу понять причину:

Есть массив структур (для упрощения я оставил только 2), в каждой структуре может быть поле parent (указатель на родительскую структуру) или не быть (по сути - корневая структура).

Я хочу обойти все структуры и построить JS код (в приведенном коде его нет, не суть) в котором данные дочерних структур вложены в родительские типа

родитель->{потомок1->{подпотомок1, подпотомок2, ...}, подпотомок2->{...}, ...}

Алгоритм работает следующим образом:
Сначала ищутся структуры без родителей, потом для каждой найденной структуры ищутся структуры у которых parent = id родительской структуры и т.д.

В моем примере должна было бы сначала найтись структура с id = 'page1', а потом структура с id = 'page2'

Но происходит какое-то зацикливание, которое я не могу понять.

почему-то

```
echo "|".$parentNodeName."|<br>"; // ОТЛАДОЧНЫЙ КОД
```

выдает правильный входной параметр,но уже внутри функтора в функции array_filter $parentNodeName пустой :(

В чём может быть дело?

```
// сформировать JS код по узлу
function prepareContentBlock($nodes, $parentNodeName)
{
echo "|".$parentNodeName."|<br>"; // ОТЛАДОЧНЫЙ КОД

    // найти все блоки, у которых родители $parentNodeName
    $selectNodes = array_filter($nodes, function($node){

        if ((array_key_exists('parent', $node) == true) && ($node['parent'] == $parentNodeName))
            return true;

        if ((array_key_exists('parent', $node) == false) && ($parentNodeName == ''))
            return true;

        return false;
    });

    print_r($selectNodes); // ОТЛАДОЧНЫЙ КОД
    echo "<br>"; // ОТЛАДОЧНЫЙ КОД

    // сформировать JS код
    $totalCode = '[';

    foreach ($selectNodes as $node)
    {
        $contentCode = (array_key_exists('id', $node)) ? prepareContentBlock($nodes, $node['id']) : '';     

        $nodeCode = '';
        $totalCode .= '{'.$nodeCode.'},';
    }

    $totalCode .= ']';

    return $totalCode;
}

function prepareUserContent($userName)
{
    // информация о блоках данных
    $blocks = array(
        array(
            'id'        =>  'page1',
            'order'     =>  -1,
        ),

        array(
            'id'        => 'page2',
            'parent'    => 'page1',
        ),
    );

    $content = prepareContentBlock($blocks, '');

    echo $content; // ОТЛАДОЧНЫЙ КОД
    exit(0); // ОТЛАДОЧНЫЙ КОД

    return $content;
}
```

Comment: Как я понял (проверил на тестовых переменных) все дело в том, что из функтора снаружи не видно других переменных. Как это тогда можно исправить?

Comment: use($parentNodeName) после function($node)

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov, не получилось - ошибка
"Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_USE in my.php"

надо было внутри функции поставить?

Comment: @Zhihar прочитайте комментарий к Вашему ответу

Comment: Почитайте внимательней про область видимости переменных в PHP. Этот язык один из лояльных к стилю написания, что в свою очередь сказывается на затруднённом поиске пропаж.

Answer (score 0):

Немного изменил вывод (для наглядности), использовал `use($parentNodeName)` для замыкания перенной в колбэке:

*"Замыкания могут также наследовать переменные из родительской области видимости. Любая подобная переменная должна быть объявлена в конструкции use."*

убрал тернарник `array_key_exists('id', $node)`, так как в конкретом примере условие всегда истинно.

```
<?php

// сформировать JS код по узлу
function prepareContentBlock($nodes, $parentNodeName)
{
    // найти все блоки, у которых родители $parentNodeName
    $selectNodes = array_filter($nodes, function ($node) use($parentNodeName){
        if ((array_key_exists('parent', $node) == true) && ($node['parent'] == $parentNodeName))
            return true;
        if ((array_key_exists('parent', $node) == false) && ($parentNodeName == ''))
            return true;
        return false;
    });
    // сформировать JS код
    $totalCode = '[';
    foreach ($selectNodes as $node)
    {
        $res = prepareContentBlock($nodes, $node['id']);
        $contentCode = $res !== "[]" ? $res : $node['val'];     
        $totalCode .= '{'. $node['id'].':'.$contentCode.',' . '},';
    }
    $totalCode .= ']';
    return $totalCode;
}

function prepareUserContent($userName)
{
    // информация о блоках данных
    $blocks = array(
        array(
            'id'        =>  'page1',
            'order'     =>  -1,
            'val'       =>  'a', 
        ),
        array(
            'id'        => 'page2',
            'parent'    => 'page1',
            'val'       =>  'b',
        ),
        array(
            'id'        => 'page3',
            'parent'    => 'page1',
            'val'       =>  'c',
        ),
        array(
            'id'        => 'page4',
            'parent'    => 'page3',
            'val'       =>  'd',
        ),

    );
    $content = prepareContentBlock($blocks, '');
    return $content;
}

echo prepareUserContent('noname');

?>
```

результат:

```
[{page1:[{page2:b,},{page3:[{page4:d,},],},],},]
```